# Multiples upgrades de una misma versión de GeneXus en el mismo equipo

Tags: genexus

Normalmente trabajo con varias versiones de GeneXus instaladas en mi equipo, incluso con varios upgrades de una misma versión.

La instalación la realizo directamente desde el .zip y luego GeneXus /install.

La consulta viene porque, como parte del proceso, agrego las siguientes claves al archivo genexus.exe.config:

```
<add key="UserAppDataPath" value="C:\temp\Genexus\GX17UBeta\UserAppData"/>
<add key="ProgramDataPath" value="C:\temp\Genexus\GX17UBeta\ProgramDataPath"/>
```

Actualmente lo hago por costumbre y no tengo claro si sigue siendo necesario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario que realices esa configuración.

Debería funcionarte todo OK sin realizar esos cambios. Puede ser útil para asegurarte que los configs y temporales de cada versión quedan totalmente aislados de los de otro upgrade que tengas.

Lo que sí, de NO usar esas entradas, antes de abrir un GX hay que ejecutar un "/install" primero para que se actualice el cache de packages que tiene esa versión de GX que va a usar, sobre todo si tenes patterns instalados en GX.

Comment: Por ahí viene el tema entonces. De todas formas creo que el /install igual hay que ejecutarlo con o sin esas claves siempre que lo haga mediante el .zip.